# CSS3 transforms: sending input to a transformed div

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms, css-animations

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/bnookala/b2Yz8/3/ and this is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/bnookala/b2Yz8/3/embedded/result/

The behavior is pretty straightforward: after clicking on the red div, the 3D transform occurs and the blue div is made visible. Trying to reverse this behavior (by removing the `flip` class), however, does not work. The second `jQuery.bind` does not receive the `click` event - it is being captured by the red div. This is also apparent in that the input box (in the blue div) cannot receive mouse focus. I've tried setting z-indexes to solve this problem, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the target of your click event and this will work:

```
$("#card").on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('flip');                
});
```

Comment: Toggling the class doesn't fix the problem of being unable to give input focus to the text input, though.

Comment: after flip, add: $('.face input').focus()

Comment: Well, that's one way to get around it... But I'm looking more for a solution done through CSS. What if I have other types of content than just the text input, for example? i.e: If I had a button in the blue div, how could I expect any bound functions to actually fire when clicked?

Comment: You have a click hander for the wrapper, this will also trigger on the child elements. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Sorry for seeming stubborn - but wouldn't handlers on ".face.front" and ".face.back" only target the child elements? Something still doesn't seem right here.